# How can i get projects within a date range in drf

Tags: django-rest-framework

```
`project = Project.objects.filter(
        Q(startDate__range=(startDate, endDate))|
        Q(endDate__range=(startDate, endDate)),
        **ProjectParam
    ).order_by(const.START_TIME_PROPERTY)`
```

i want to get all projects between param date range.but here is a problem that i am facing
like if i request get projects api with start date jan-1 and end date apil-4 and there are some projects

```
project A start date jan-3 enddate feb-5
project B start date Feb-4 enddate Sep-7
project C start date March-4  enddate Sep - 8
project D start date May-5 enddate Jun-7
```

Then Project A, B, C will be return 
But, If one project-A have start date Jan-1 and endDate Sep-5 and i request with start date March-1 and end date march-30
Then i am not getting Project-A

Comment: So you want to return projects that overlap?

Comment: i want to return all projects not only between the requested range but also the projects those start date or end date fall is in the range...like if i requested with start date and end date (1 march to 30 march) and one project has start date 25 march and end date 4 april that should also return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Alternative 1: *Contained* elements

If you want to obtain projects that are "contained" in the data time range, you should filter on:

```
project = Project.objects.filter(
    Q(startDate__lte=startDate, endDate__gte=endDate)
    **ProjectParam
).order_by(const.START_TIME_PROPERTY)
```

This will list all projects that started at or before the `startDate`, and ended after or on the `endDate`.

## Alternative 2: *Overlapping* elements

If you want all projects with an overlap, you can filter with:

```
project = Project.objects.filter(
    Q(startDate__lte=endDate, endDate__gte=startDate)
    **ProjectParam
).order_by(const.START_TIME_PROPERTY)
```

This works because all elements that do *not* belong to the overlap have a `startDate` that is greater than `endDate`, or an `endDate` that les less than the `startDate`. So we negate this condition.